# A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>

Tags: reactjs

I installed the most recent version of react-router-dom. Then downgraded version to @4.3.1. I still get the error that I should wrap Route in a Routes. As I know, this happens only to more recent versions. I checked the package.json file, I am sure that my version is @4.3.1.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import Products from "./components/products";
import Posts from "./components/posts";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Dashboard from "./components/admin/dashboard";
import ProductDetails from "./components/productDetails";
import NotFound from "./components/notFound";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="content">
          <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
          <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
          <Route path="/admin" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-router-dom` v4, you need to wrap `Route`s in a `Router`, and include a `<Switch />` Try this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route, 
  Switch, 
Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import Products from "./components/products";
import Posts from "./components/posts";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Dashboard from "./components/admin/dashboard";
import ProductDetails from "./components/productDetails";
import NotFound from "./components/notFound";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="content">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
            <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

See the docs [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for more details